# Using boost variant with different shared_ptr<T> types

Tags: gcc, boost, c++14, shared-ptr, boost-variant

I want to use a boost::variant to effectively hold a union of a few different types as follows.

```
using VariantType = boost::variant<
    std::shared_ptr<StructA>, 
    std::shared_ptr<StructB>
>;
```

I put together a prototype on [**Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f01d3186208b044a) where it at least compiles.

```
VariantType variant = std::make_shared<StructA>(1, 'a', 3);
boost::apply_visitor(output{}, variant);    
std::cout << variant.which() << std::endl;
variant =  std::make_shared<StructB>('b', 'c');
boost::apply_visitor(output{}, variant);    
std::cout << variant.which() << std::endl;
```

prints out the following as expected:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lrt && ./a.out
StructA: CommonStruct: 123 1a3
0
StructB: CommonStruct: 456 bc
1
```

Now on to the crux of the matter, actual code (which works fine in Visual Studio 2015) however it does not compile on gcc 4.9.1.  (with different types in place of StructA & StructB above).  Can someone help me figure out what the meaning of this cryptic error message is and how to work around it.  All my structs are POD structs with explicit constructors similar to those in StructA and StructB.

Here is the gcc 4.9.1 error message.

```
error: call of overloaded 'initialize(void*, boost::move_detail::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<ReportS‌​tatusRequest, std::default_elete<ReportStatusRequest> >&>::type)' is ambiguous.
                 )
                 ^
/spare1/aaron/0339/ltib/rootfs/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1561:17: note: candidates are:
In file included from /spare1/aaron/0339/ltib/rootfs/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:30:0,
                 from /spare1/aaron/0339/ltib/rootfs/usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
                 from ../../include/fhdb/FHDBUtil.h:17,
                 from FHDBUtil.cpp:18:
```

This error occurs for each of the variant types in the **GenericSendMessage** typedef (shown later).  Each of these error messages is accompanied with a number of gcc note warnings as follows:

```
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:115:24: note: static int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize(void*, boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::param2_T) [with BaseIndexPair = boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list6<std::shared_ptr<ConnectRequest>, std::shared_ptr<DisconnectRequest>, std::shared_ptr<GenerateFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<ReportStatusRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveComplete> > > >::initializer_node, mpl_::int_<1> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list5<std::shared_ptr<DisconnectRequest>, std::shared_ptr<GenerateFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<ReportStatusRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveComplete> > > >::initializer_node, mpl_::int_<2> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list4<std::shared_ptr<GenerateFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<ReportStatusRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveComplete> > > >::initializer_node, mpl_::int_<3> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list3<std::shared_ptr<ReportStatusRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveComplete> > > >::initializer_node, mpl_::int_<4> >; Iterator = boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<std::shared_ptr<RetrieveFHDBRequest>, std::shared_ptr<RetrieveComplete> > >; boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::param2_T = std::shared_ptr<RetrieveFHDBRequest>&&]
             static int initialize(void* dest, param2_T operand)
```

This error message corresponds to the actual VariantType defined below

```
using GenericSendMessage = boost::variant<
    std::shared_ptr<ConnectRequest>, 
    std::shared_ptr<DisconnectRequest>,
    std::shared_ptr<GenerateFHDBRequest>,
    std::shared_ptr<ReportStatusRequest>,
    std::shared_ptr<RetrieveFHDBRequest>,
    std::shared_ptr<RetrieveComplete>
>;
```

Comment: can you post an actual [MCVE] which exhibits this error? please post the definitions of the structs you use. also the *full* error message is missing. which boost version are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, firstly I replicated the same behavior on coliru via a live demo, which works fine, the problem is that the error output should occur on gcc 4.9.1 (actually it is on a powerPC), my minimal example is a stripped down bare bones replication of my problem.  The details of the actual platform problems are shown in the cryptic gcc error output which I do not understand - which was the main reason for posting the question

Comment: you can use `g++-4.9` on coliru, it compiles without any errors http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6353c2f719e6bca

Comment: @m.s I guess the problem may be PowerPC specific, I am using CodeSourcery for PowerPC

Comment: still some things are not clear: which boost version are you using? what is the full error message? in which line of the above example does that error occur?

Comment: @m.s boost 1.61 (on windows fine) on PowerPC (the error in the question) - the full error message is in the question (it is length and wrapped so it might not stand out)

Comment: no, this is just part of the error message, it's just the `note` part

Comment: @m.s Yeah, I feel like an idiot, I realized that a few mins ago, looking for the detailed error.... error: call of overloaded 'initialize(void*, boost::move_detail::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<ReportStatusRequest, std::default_elete<ReportStatusRequest> >&>::type)' is ambiguous.  The same error occurs for each of the vartiant types

Comment: a wild guess: are you using `make_unique` instead of `make_shared` in your actual code? this provokes the same error message: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9526f8c3e724b5c7

Comment: @m.s Fantastic, thanks that was it! Post a quick answer and I'll select it, thanks for your persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message states:

```
error: call of overloaded 
'initialize(void*, 
    boost::move_detail::remove_reference<
        std::unique_ptr<ReportS‌​tatusRequest,
                        std::default_delete<ReportStatusRequest> >&>::type)' is ambiguous.
```

Note the `unique_ptr` part! This suggests you are trying to assign a `unique_ptr` to the variant type.

This indeed does not compile in gcc-4.9: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9526f8c3e724b5c7

But it does compile in later gcc versions.

**solution**:
assign a `shared_ptr` instead of a `unique_ptr`.